# Execute if no exception thrown

Tags: python, exception, python-3.x, try-catch, finally

I have some code I want to execute if an exception is **not** thrown.

Currently I'm doing this:

```
try:
    return type, self.message_handlers[type](self, length - 1)
finally:
    if not any(self.exc_info()):
        self.last_recv_time = time.time()
```

Can this be improved on? Is this the best way to do it?

### Update0

> The optional else clause is executed if and when control flows off the
>   end of the try clause.
>
> Currently, control “flows off the end” except in the case of an
>   exception or the execution of a return, continue, or break statement.

Comment: Maybe I understand this wrong... but if you `return` something without exception, how can you execute anything afterwards within this method?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code suggests that you don't want to catch the exception if it occurs, so why not simply

```
result = type, self.message_handlers[type](self, length - 1)
self.last_recv_time = time.time()
return result
```

(Am I missing anything?)

Comment: No you aren't. This does what he asked for. :-)

Comment: I don't think you're missing anything. Simple is best.

Answer (score 28):

```
try:
   tmp = type, self.message_handlers[type](self, length - 1)
except Exception:
   pass #or handle error, or just "raise" to re-raise
else:
   self.last_recv_time = time.time()
   return tmp
```

Comment: Nothing will be returned if an exception is thrown within the try-clause

Comment: @Matt: The `else` clause won't be executed under any circustances, since control can't reach the end of the `try` block.

Comment: I'm sorry the else clause will really never be executed.

Comment: @Niklas, Matt, Sven: Thanks, you were all right - I'd copied the code in a bit too quickly. I've corrected it now, but I like Sven's solution.