# What is the best way to execute code when a test does not raise an error in Python?

Tags: python, exception, try-except

Background story: I am processing some messy data sheets made in Excel. Reading this with pandas (preferable) does sometimes conserve the Excel data type of the cells. As all entries I would like to process have a value in a certain column that can be converted to an integer, I would like to execute a code block when this column can be converted (i.e. does not throw an error). I know there are some ways to work around this problem, but I would like to know what you would do if you would like to execute code **when no error is returned from a statement without the try/except statement.**

The try/except block is what I came up with so far:

```py
try:
    int(x)

    # Big code chunk goes here
    ....

    # Exception can be found much further down in the code
except ValueError:
    pass
```

This feels a bit odd to me. To make it a bit more readable the code chunk could be placed in a function, but what I am really looking for is something like this:

```py
if int(x) == NoError:
    # Lets go ahead with the code chunk
    ....
```

Are there nice ways of implementing something like this for a general use case?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911999/execute-if-no-exception-thrown) answer your question?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you want: continuing with no error is the normal mode of operation.  The `else` clause is in any tutorial on try/except.  As such, your needs are unclear.

Comment: You could always try `str.isnumeric`

Comment: The try/except is the normal way to handle this. You could bury it in a function that catches the error and returns, say, `None` and use that as the sentinel, but I think the try/except is more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you possibly are looking for is a `try-except-else` block

```py
try:
    int(x)
except ValueError:
    ...
else:
    # No error
```

Answer (score 3):

As you are working with pandas, you might be able to use [`pandas.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html).

It explicitly handles errors:

> errors{‘ignore’, ‘raise’, ‘coerce’}, default ‘raise’
>
> If ‘raise’, then invalid parsing will raise an exception.
>
> If ‘coerce’, then invalid parsing will be set as NaN.
>
> If ‘ignore’, then invalid parsing will return the input.

Answer (score 0):

Use [contextlib.suppress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html?highlight=suppress#contextlib.suppress):

```py
from contextlib import suppress

with suppress(ValueError):
    int(x)
    # Big code chunk goes here
    ...
```

Comment: This will execute the code always right? I want to check if it throws an error. If it does I don't want to execute anything.